# Does critical event caused by RadeonSettings.exe mean Nvidia GPU card has hardware fault?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, gpu, amd-radeon, interrupts

I have been getting "System Interrupts" a few times every day on my Windows 10 PC. This is slowing down my PC and is getting irritating. From the reliability history (see screenshot below), I can see critical event caused by `RadeonSettings.exe`.

Is it a fair conclusion that the most likely hardware problem causing `System Interrupts` to be Nvidia GPU card?

[image]

Comment: nVidia don't make Radeon, that's an AMD brand... Are you using the latest drivers for your GPU?

Comment: You're right indeed. I'm using latest driver for Nvidia card. It auto-updates, so I'm quite sure it's latest. I'm using AMD Ryzen 7 CPU. Oh dear. Could this mean my CPU has hardware fault?

Comment: The Ryzen 7 has an APU.